When does the Kodaira dimension equal the algebraic dimension?
I am using the notation from Huybrechts's Complex Geometry.
The canonical ring of a complex manifold is defined as:
$$R(X) := \bigoplus_{m \geq 0} H^0(X, \mathcal{K}_X^{\otimes m}).$$
The Kodaira dimension is defined as:
$$\text{Kod}(X) := \begin{cases}
-\infty & \text{if } R(X) = \mathbb{C}, \\ 
\text{trdeg}_{\mathbb{C}} Q(R(X)) - 1 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}$$
In Proposition 2.2.28, it states:
$$\text{Kod}(X) = \text{trdeg}_{\mathbb{C}} Q_0(R(X)) \leq \text{trdeg}_{\mathbb{C}} K(X),$$
where $K(X)$ is the field of meromorphic functions on $X$ and $Q_0(R(X))$ is considered as a graded integral domain.

From my understanding, this result hinges on when the meromorphic functions are in a one-to-one correspondence with the global sections of the canonical bundle on $X$. So what would be an example of such case ?

Wait, I just realized you can almost always cook up the global section to meromorphic functions and vice versa. So the question should be when they differ. And an example of this is the projective space because $\mathcal{O}(-m)$ admits no global sections. Can someone confirm ?

I deleted a comment based on a misreading. The terminology you are looking for is "general type", and examples are given by  hypersurfaces of degree at least $n+2$ in $\mathbf P^n$.

@LazzaroCampeotti what do you mean by hyperfurfaces of degree $n+2$, in $P^n$ ? aren't we embeding in $P^n$ ? General type as in the first chern class of the tangent bundle is negative ?

"what do you mean by hyperfurfaces of degree n+2 in P^n?" I mean a subvariety of  P^n defined by a single homogeneous polynomial of degree at least n+2.

"aren't we embeding in P^n?" I don't understand what you mean by this question.

"General type as in the first chern class of the tangent bundle is negative?" That depends exactly what one means by negativity of a class. "General type" is just some terminology that means exactly what you ask about, namely that the Kodaira dimension is maximal. I mentioned it only to give you a search term to help find examples of the kind of objects you are looking for.

@LazzaroCampeotti I was a bit confused how the degree is bigger than $n$ since $X\subset P^n$, but it hasn't to do anything with dimension.
